# How can I sync my photos on my Windows PC with Google Photos now that Google Drive is no longer synced automatically with Google Photos?

Tags: windows, sync, google-photos

I used to just drop them in the `Google Drive/Google Photos` folder and they would be uploaded automatically, but now that Google Drive is no longer synced with Google Photos, I don't know what to do... I want to put the photos in Google Photos, not in Google Drive. And I wonder when it would be safe to delete my `Google Drive/Google Photos` folder...

Answer (score 1):

Google has published for that purpose
[Backup and Sync](https://photos.google.com/apps).

This app for Windows or Mac will back up photos from your computer, camera or
SD card to Google Drive and Photos, and the app will upload a copy to both
Google services for you:

- Download and install, that start the app
- Click on *Get Started* and sign-in to your Google account
- Choose whether you want to just back up photos and videos, or other files as well,
  then click on *Next*
- You can select from which folders you want to save your photos, and
  whether the photos are to be saved in "High quality" or "Original quality".
- Click on *Advanced settings* to choose whether you want to sync with Google Drive.
- Click on *Start* to backup.

Comment: Oh, I have that app installed - how do I point it at a folder that contains my photos? And how do I avoid wasting storage space by uploading photos to both services?

Comment: The process is basically described in my answer. For more details see for example [this article](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/google-will-disconnect-photos-and-drive-heres-how-to-keep-your-photos-synced/).

Comment: Is this only a 1-way sync though? If you delete a photo from Google Photos, will it get deleted from Google Drive and your computer?

Comment: Yes, this is 1-way sync, only from your computer to Google Photos. If you delete or edit a photo on Google Photos, nothing changes on your computer. If you add a photo to Google Photos through another channel (for example upload from phone) it will not be added to your computer.